# How to place audio outside of datatable?

Tags: javascript

Alloy Audio UI example is provided in https://alloyui.com/examples/audio/real-world

Data table row click can be achieved via

```
$('#mp3table').on( 'click', 'tbody tr', function () {
  var rowData = table.row( this ).data();

  // can modify the audio player's source here
  ...

  audio.play();
} );
```

I would like to place the audio outside of the datatable and cannot find a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to first declare your audio instance outside of your table, and then re-use it as needed.

So in your case, when table rows are clicked, you can reference and re-use the same audio instance for audio playback, as follows:

```
// Declare your audio instance, outside of the table
var audio = new Y.Audio({ 
    boundingBox: '#yourAudioElement' 
}).render();

$('#mp3table').on( 'click', 'tbody tr a', function () {

  // Extract the audio url from this button. 
  var audioUrl = $(this).data('url');

  // Pause the audio instance if it's currently playing
  audio.pause();
  // Update the url of the audio instance
  audio.set('url', audioUrl);
  // Load the new data from the new audioUrl
  audio.load();
  // Play the new sound via the same audio object
  audio.play();

});
```

And your supporting HTML could look something like this:

```
<div id="yourAudioElement"></div>

<table id="mp3table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="#" data-url="https://alloyui.com/audio/zelda.mp3">Click to hear zelda</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <a href="#" data-url="http://www.noiseaddicts.com/samples_1w72b820/4929.mp3">Click to hear bird</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's Nice of you Dacre Denny. Can you please help me with a html snippet with code with one sample mp3 link so that i will take it from there...Please kindly help me.

Comment: Hi Kathir, you are welcome - I have expanded and updated the answer to show you how you could provide HTML to make this work. Please let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: Dacre Denny, i have some questions as well. Do you support via email? all are one word minor questions. In stackoverflow it might get down voted. pls kindly let me know

Comment: you can contact me via my website, see my profile for the link